# Sending emails, with send/recieved notificaitons via Sharepoint 2013 Designer workflow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow

Does anyone know if it is possible to send an email, via SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow, that utilizes "email received" and/or 'email read" notifications?

I created a workflow that sends an email when various conditions (e.g., statuses, dates, choice), in a SharePoint list, are met. I would like to be able to track whether or not the recipients received (and even perhaps read) the email.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!